# background-size:contain and width property on a <ul>

Tags: html, wordpress, background-image, css

I have a WordPress submenu which has a background-image set with a background-size:contain. Its width is big (280%) to be sure it's full screen even in high resolutions. Here's a screenshot from Firefox (and this is how it should be displayed).

[image]
[*(high res)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrPcK.png)

On Chrome and IE instead, it's displayed like this:
[image]
[*(high res)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Te6.png)

Why its width is so small?

**[Here](http://bassano.cngei.it/beta/)**'s the website live.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather tricky to explain!

It seems you have that `<ul>` tag nested within multiple `<div>` tags. One of them has a set width. I believe it's the `<div>` with your logo, name, and search bar in it. It's set to `920px`. Since your `<ul>` tag is nested within this `<div>`, if you set the width to 100%, the biggest it can get is `920px` wide. To fix it, you must take it out of the `<div>` with the set width.

The reason `width:280%;` works is because it's > `2700px`.. which would fill out any screen. Except Chrome and IE are very confused on why you'd want to do that!

I'd like to stay and help you fix it up, but sadly I'll be heading out! If you don't happen to get it working by the time I get back I'll update my post.

Comment: First of all: thanks for your interest! :) Problem is it's difficult to test things on IE and Chrome.. Firebug Lite isn't so good as "normal" Firebug.. and every time there's some thing working on FF and not on others it really sucks :P

Comment: I came back and noticed your page still looks the same, so I whipped this up for you: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/XU8kK/4/). Ignore my amazing colour scheme! I just did that so you can see how it works better, obviously modify it to match your website. My only concern is that it isn't responsive, but I don't think that's a big deal to you

Comment: It's really strange.. it's not the 920px div.. I commented out all containing divs CSS. Still same behavior on Chrome an IE. I think it's some styling of the UL. I'm trying to adapt your structure

Comment: This is more strange too.. I solved setting .nav-menu .sub-menu, .nav-menu .children to width:2200px instead of 280%... -.-